# Pagination issue in Report Viewer 11 in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, reportviewer

I am using ReportViewer 11 to display a report inside an iframe (aspx page is loaded into iframe). It displays first page properly. But when I click on next page, it loads the first page again. Even if I type in page number manually into the textbox, it loads first page only. It seems like, it doesn't fire the pagenavigation event in the server side. If I set the currentpage property to 2 in code behind, then also it loads page 1 only no matter what settings I provide. 
Searched for this for days. Got no solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply this logic

1. Store the records in container1
2. Pass the records to container2
3. print 5 records(or may be more) from container2
4. when "next" button is pressed print next 5 from container2
5. and so on.

I dont know whether this will help you, but records from database can be paginated in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this logic too. But the main problem is that ReportViewer.CurrentPage is 0 always (in my case) even when the "next" button is pressed. So it will again show the container1 records. This is my code:

```
public void SetReportData(ref ReportViewer objRptVwr, ReportParameter[] rptParam, string moduleName, string reportName, string dsName, System.Data.DataTable dtFinal){ 
        objRptVwr.Reset();
        objRptVwr.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        objRptVwr.LocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ReportViewer/" + moduleName + "/" + reportName + ".rdlc");

        if (rptParam != null)
            objRptVwr.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParam);

        objRptVwr.ShowPrintButton = true;
        objRptVwr.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
        objRptVwr.AsyncRendering = false;
        objRptVwr.InteractivityPostBackMode = InteractivityPostBackMode.AlwaysSynchronous;
        objRptVwr.ShowBackButton = true;
        objRptVwr.SizeToReportContent = false;
        objRptVwr.PageCountMode = PageCountMode.Actual;
        objRptVwr.ShowExportControls = true;
        objRptVwr.ShowPageNavigationControls = true;
        objRptVwr.ShowToolBar = true;
        objRptVwr.ShowWaitControlCancelLink = false;
        objRptVwr.ShowZoomControl = true;
        objRptVwr.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        objRptVwr.ExportContentDisposition = ContentDisposition.AlwaysInline;        
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource(dsName, (System.Data.DataTable)dtFinal);
        objRptVwr.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        objRptVwr.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
        objRptVwr.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did that the generated buttons will be according to the  list size.
Each buttons(may be li tag) will have a textfield containing value like 0,5,10 and so on dynamically(In case of 5 elements per page).

A button is clicked, the value of that textfield(e.g index) I got and shifted the resulset position to index and print the records upto 5 elements.